# make infos in one line using Twig

Tags: html, css, twig

to make it short, i need to make those informations inline in my site : 
Juste like that :

> **Famille** : Open Sans  —  **Variante** : Regular Italic
>
> **Taille** : 15px  —  **Interlignage** : 25px  —   **Paragraphe** : 15px
>
> **Couleur** : grey_3

This is my code :

```
{% include "../component/1-atom/Typographies/sg-typo-hierarchisation.twig" with {
                typo_hierarchisation: [
                    {
                        title: "Famille",
                        value: "Fira Sans",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Variante",
                        value: "ExtraBold",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Taille",
                        value: "50px",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Interlignage",
                        value: "50px",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Paragraphe",
                        value: "25px",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Couleur",
                        value: "couleur de l’univers",
                        value_2: "primary_ {{ univers }}",
                        class_regular: "fw-regular-i",
                        class_bold: "fw-bold-i",
                    }
                ]
            }%}
```

In this is the included file :

```
<ul class="sg-typo-hierarchisation">
    {% for item in typo_hierarchisation %}
    {% set trait = "<i class='trait'> — </i>" %}
        <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class={{item.class_regdivar ? item.class_regular: ""}}>{{ item.title ? item.title : "" }}</span>
            <span class={{item.class_bold}}>{{ item.value ? " : " ~ item.value : "" }}</span>
            {{ item.value_2 ? ('<span class=' ~ item.class_bold ~ '>' ~ trait ~  item.value_2  ~ '</span>')|raw : '' }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Tell now i have this render:

> **Famille** : Fira Sans
>
> **Variante** : ExtraBold
>
> **Taille** : 50px
>
> **Interlignage** : 50px
>
> **Paragraphe** : 25px
>
> **Couleur** : couleur de l’univers — primary_ {{ univers }}

***Edit:***
In the web site i have this in the inspector :

```
<ul class="sg-typo-hierarchisation">
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Famille</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : Fira Sans</span>

        </li>
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Variante</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : ExtraBold</span>

        </li>
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Taille</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : 50px</span>

        </li>
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Interlignage</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : 50px</span>

        </li>
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Paragraphe</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : 25px</span>

        </li>
                <li class="sg-typo-hierarchisation-item">
            <span class="">Couleur</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"> : couleur de l’univers</span>
            <span class="fw-bold-i"><i class="trait"> — </i>primary_ {{ univers }}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `spans` are inline by default; if they are not in what you are seeing, then you must have applied CSS that changes that behavior.

Comment: Can't make a css with this render (please see my post i edited it)

Comment: No clue what you mean by that. What are generating the HTML output via your template, and styling the output, supposed to have to do with each other?

Comment: You need to make the list items display as inline for what you want here.

Comment: I would have liked to put each group of span in an 'li', instead using CSS : ```<li> <span> ...</span>    <span> ...</span>     <span> ...</span>   </li>``` X 3

Comment: Yeah well then place the `li` tags _outside_ of the loop …?

Comment: You get an individual LI around every SPAN, because you placed the opening and closing LI tags _inside_ the loop construct. If you want one LI around _all_ SPANs - then you just need to put the opening and closing LI tag _outside_ of the loop.

Comment: @DarkBee, Thanks for your response, will, that's why i put this post, to find another way to passing data  !

Comment: If you are in control of how the input data is presented - then just introduce an additional array level there, group your attribute objects into those - and then add an additional loop for the output.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you for your interpretation anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reformat your data in you want to "group" attributes. At this point your are passing one big array, which is impossible to group.

```html
{% set typo_hierarchisation = [
    [
        { 'title' : 'Famille', value: 'Fira Sans' },
        { 'title' : 'Variante', value : 'ExtraBold' },
    ],[
        { 'title': 'Taille', value: '50px' },
        { 'title': 'Interlignage', value : '50px' },
        { 'title': 'Paragraphe', value: '25px' },
    ],
] %}


<ul>
{% for group in typo_hierarchisation %}
    <li>
        {% for item in group %}
        <div>
            <span>{{ item.title }}</span>
            <span>{{ item.value }}</span>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/ogr1ph)

---

*Note: I've used a `div` to "group" the attributes, keep in mind this is a block element by default so you should add some extra CSS to put them next to each other*